# Docker CMD - Path to script

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

How to pass the path of the script file to the `CMD` in the Dockerfile?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as base

EXPOSE 8080    

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY run/ .

RUN mvn clean install

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY --from=base /app/data/startup.sh ./startup.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "startup.sh"]

CMD ["startup.sh", "start"]
```

When I gave `CMD ["/app/startup.sh", "start"]`, throws the below error

```
Cannot start service myapp: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/app/startup.sh": stat 
/app/startup.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

The documentation says the path would be relative to the WORKDIR, so I tried passing the scriptname alone as it is now - `CMD ["startup.sh", "start"]` which resulted in the below error:

```
Cannot start service myapp: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "service.sh": executable file 
not found in $PATH: unknown
```

The startup.sh is a simple script file with a shebang - #!/bin/sh

Am I missing anything here? I am using docker desktop for windows and get the error when I run `docker-compose up` just fyi.

Please share how I can resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you double-check that the script has Unix line endings?  If it's trying to run `/bin/sh\r` as the script interpreter you'll get errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the file to `/app/data` in this step `COPY --from=base /app/data/`

So try:

`CMD ["/app/data/startup.sh", "start"]`

Comment: So sorry, there was a typo from end. I updated the path in the questions.

Comment: In this case `startup.sh` wouldn't be correct?

Comment: What about `COPY --from=base /app/data/startup.sh /app/startup.sh`

Answer (score 1):

```
CMD ["/app/data/startup.sh", "start"]
```

should work

Comment: So sorry, there was a typo from end. I updated the path in the question.

Comment: I would write the copy command absolute. Have you tried this?

Comment: Do you mean `COPY --from=base /app/data/startup.sh /app/startup.sh`?